# Using Hibernate Queries

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm trying to use hiberate query for quite alot of SQL, is there a way to rewrite this sql to make it cleaner. I'm also getting variable is never used for`'Query paymentdate'`

```
  public void addPrevious(TodaysDate Date){
            String paymentDate = ("SELECT PAYMENTDATE FROM table1  where DATE = (SELECT ID FROM _DATE WHERE ID = ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM _DATE WHERE ID < ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM _DATE ) ))");
            String reportingUnit = ("SELECT REPORTING_UNIT FROM table1  where DATE = (SELECT ID FROM _DATE WHERE ID = ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM _DATE WHERE ID < ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM _DATE ) ))");
            String insertLastDate =  ("INSERT INTO table1(PAYMENTDATE, REPORTING_UNIT, Date) VALUES  ("+id+" ,"+paymentDate+", "+amount+", "+asOfDate+")");

            Query paymentdate = getSession().createQuery(paymentDate);
            Query report = getSession().createQuery(reportingunit);

        }
```

Comment: replace `=` with `IN`. `... where DATE IN (...`

Comment: You are defining the varialbe `Query paymentdate` but never use it. The compiler considers it useless and warns until you use or remove it.

Comment: @Selaron So could I just do 'getSession().createQuery(paymentDate);' and remove 'Query paymentdate =' and have the same result?@

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala Thanks, I was wondering if there was a way to combine my selects into one statement but still have the variables to use in my insert?

Comment: @Liights you can use join query for this